# Apache solr decide solr search results priorty

Tags: java, php, solr, lucene

My scenario is , I need to sort results from solr search results by fields

for example, I have two fields in solr document

```
title, description
```

and suppose i query "xxxx" then documents for which title field contains "xxxx" should be top on results.

I tried with

```
&qf=title^5 description^2
```

but its not working , thanks in advance.

Note : I am using solr 5.0

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? What results are you getting, vs what you want to get?

Comment: I am getting the results , but top results should have 'xxxx' in title, I am getting titles  on top , which does not have 'xxxx'

Comment: I'm fairly confident that the dismax qf attribute does, indeed, work [as documented](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#qf_.28Query_Fields.29).  This [just isn't enough information](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help diagnose your problem.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I fairly new to solr. You can try putting more weight on the title as if the description score is computed to be much higher than the title (via TF * IDF) the boosting will have a low impact on the results you get.

Comment: tried giving more weights to title but not working

Comment: Are you sorting by any field? What does debugQuery show (you can add debugQuery=true to the query or use the administration interface to get debug score information)?

Comment: Please try &qf= title^5 description